# How to install Nodejs using bash script in Windows Server 2012

Tags: node.js, bash, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a bash file. It has to install some dependency apps like Nodejs(MSI file) and Chrome(EXE file) when I run it in Windows server.
Can you help me, please?